# In Struts 1, What is the Default Value of Type Attribute of <action> tag?

Tags: struts-1

In Struts 1, if the type attribute of the `<action>` tag has no value, what does it mean?  Is there a default value for the `type` attribute that is used when it is not explicitly specified.

I'm basically trying to figure out what the following action does; as you can see it has no `type` attribute; it only has `path` and `forward` attributes:

```xml
<action path="/a/b/comp" forward="/components/d/my-comp.jsp">
</action>
```

Comment: This might be helpful     http://dlia.ir/Scientific/e_book/Technology/Electrical_Nuclear_Engine_Electronics/TK_5101_6720_Telecommunication_/022966.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action that you have included above simply redirects from `/a/b/comp.do to /components/d/my-comp.jsp`.  It is a shorthand for the following:

```xml
<action path="/a/b/comp" 
        parameter="/components/d/my-comp.jsp"
        type="org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction">
      </action>
```

So, for the action that you have included the type attribute is `org.apache.struts.actions.ForwardAction`.

Comment: For Struts 1 this should default to org.apache.struts.action.Action